# Foundation + SASS/SCSS customize sizes

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

In Foundation framework you can set behaviour for dom-elements for predefined screen sizes like: small, medium large and etc. I want to create my own size except predefined, for my specific reasons. How can to do it? Thanks.
P.S. I read about media queries: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html but I didn't understood how to use it (updated _settings.scss what to do didn't understood).

Comment: you were looking at exactly the right place. You have to learn some SCSS http://sass-lang.com/ to understand what is going on. Basically you can just override the values of the variable given by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you understand Sass and a program to compile your sass files into css. I use Compass to compile, so take a look at that.

Once you have that down, Install Foundation and start watching your sass files; watching your files will convert them into css.

You should see a partial file (they have an underscore in front of them) called _settings.scss. 99% of this file everything is commented out. Look for this section and uncomment it:

```
$small-range: (0em, 40em); /* 0, 640px */
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em); /* 641px, 1024px */
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em); /* 1025px, 1440px */
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em); /* 1441px, 1920px */
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em); /* 1921px */

$screen: "only screen";

$landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)";
$portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)";

$small-up: $screen;
$small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})";

$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})";
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})";

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})";
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})";

$xlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)})";
$xlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xlarge-range)})";

$xxlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)})";
$xxlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xxlarge-range)})";
```

The small-range, medium-range, large-range, etc are your breakpoints. All you need to do is change these values or add more breakpoints.

Comment: Hi, This I understood, but what if I need to create new dimensions for example "xxs-small". And also if i want to use this parameter for setting behavior of columns like this: xxs-small-8. Is it possible? Thanks.